# How to start microsoft-edge from a Java app

Tags: java, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I'm using the following code to open a link in Edge on a Windows 10 Surface pro 4 from a Java app

```
String[] myCommand= {"start microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com"};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myCommand, null, null);
```

However, this code is throwing an IOException. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call cmd.exe to run the command:

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com");

Comment: Thanks, that was it!